# How to do simple jquery alert window?

Tags: jquery

I've tried the following for a simple query alert popup but always get the error that the object doesn't support the property/method.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script>
$(function () {
  ("#hello").show()
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
$(function () {
  ("#hello").dialogue()
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="hello">testing.</div>
```

Comment: Is the missing `$` before `('#hello')` a typo?

Comment: You're missing the `$` sign. It is used to denote jQuery objects. For example, `$("#hello")...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `$` symbol (*jQuery*) as well as `jQuery UI` library.

```js
  $("#hello").dialog()
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="hello">testing</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing jQuery selector `$`

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#hello").show()
 //-^---
});
</script>
```

If you are looking for jQuery UI dialog then use , also you need to include jQuery ui library and css in this case

```
$(function() {
    $( "#hello" ).dialog();
});
```

Comment: That does fix the error but still no popup.  This script block is at the bottom of the page.  I'm guessing that shouldn't matter?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is

A : You are missing the $ infront e.g. `$('#element').show()`

B: Jquery does not have native dialog boxes.

If you want the alert style "popup" message, then you would need to look for a Jquery plugin that does this. [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) has one.

Other than that you can just show a div at the top of your screen, using `.show()`

Comment: It is important to make clear that (As this answert correctly states), **JQUERY DOES NOT HAVE NATIVE DIALOG BOXES**

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot the jQuery selection operator `$`.

Change your code to:

> $(function () {   $("#hello").show() });

If you are wanting to alert something you can do:

```
alert($('#hello').text())
```

Finally, you can also include a jQuery UI dialog box by doing:

```
$("#hello").dialog()
```

However, to do this ensure you have the relevant jQUery UI libraries included on your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI, which you should be if you want to use the dialog() method (**not dialogue()**).
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Edit::
Yes, as mentioned by other users, your are also not using the jQuery selector.With jQuery UI, Your code should look like $("#hello").dialog(); $("hello").show() will not be necessary for the dialogue window.